# PhpStorm. Darcula theme. Disable left gap

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, phpstorm-2017.2

How to disable the gap I've pointed to?

Or, at least, change its' color to the same as the editor area.

Distraction free mode works not as I want to.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to adjust the color [here](http://i.imgur.com/mZsJSE0.png)?

Comment: @CrazyCoder

Thank you. It has helped. Do you want to create the answer, so I could accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Gutter background** color can be changed here:

[image: gutter]